# Select disabled when selecting a value - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When selecting a value from my select I need to disable all the select as such and only show the value that I select, I have tried in several ways but I have not been able to make it work for me.

```js
import React,{useState} from 'react'

function Pruebas() {
  const [select, setSelect] = useState();

  const elselect =  () => {
   
    
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        
        <select  onChange={ elselect }>
          <option value="uno">uno</option>
          <option value="uno">dos</option>
        </select>
      </form>
      
    </div>
  )
}

export default Pruebas
```

Comment: please explain yourself clearly. do you want to disable the other option elements that are not selected in a particular select component

Comment: Do you mean something like `<select disabled={user_has_selected} onChange={ elselect }>` where `user_has_selected` is set to `true` once the user has clicked on one of the options in the select?

Comment: Yes, but how would it be in my code?